# Eclipse Editor font became unreadable small

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse editor font became unreadable small for the html file in the screen shot. It doesn't come back to normal even thought it's restarted and/or the Prespective view is reset. How to fix? It works to create a new workspace, however it's not a good option.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In editor, send `Ctrl + Shift + plus` (numeric keyboard plus key).

Or, got to `Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Structured Text Editors > Structured Text Editor Text Font`, and set font size (10 by default)